# Azure File Share mount with AAD Credentials

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-storage, azure-files

How can I log in to an Azure File Share (Azure Storage account with file sharing) with Azure AD credentials?

I would not like to deploy an Azure Domain Service.

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this with either Active Directory synced to Azure AD, and domain joined machines, or Azure AD DS, there is no other option. Full details are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404)

Answer (score -1):

Does [Kerberos Auth](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-hybrid-identities-enable?tabs=azure-portal) for Azure Files fix your issue? it seems that after a few years, they have figured this out.